# What is the significance of numbers written in django server along with GET?

Tags: python, django, django-views, get-request

I am building a django website and i noticed that within my server there often occur several lines like -

> [28/Jul/2019 22:52:24] "GET /media/images/product_images/Q0jsuTaUwKhgOhhO.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2981629

In lines like these what does the number **200** and **2981629** signify?

Also, does printing of these lines in my command line slow my server?

Comment: 200 is the status code that is returned, and 2981629 the size of the response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what are the units of size?

Comment: that should be bytes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the help. Can you also tell if using print command in django server costs any memory or time , in-short will a dozen of print statements from multiple users on the server slow it?

Comment: not that significantly no. Usually you will log it to a rotation log. It might be better to log requests to later perform "post-mortem analysis"